# Android: phone back button

Tags: android

The phone back button has me baffled. This question has been asked many times, but i have NOT got the solution. So asking again as per my requirement.

I have a home screen activity
It calls 3 activities - which in turn calls 2 activity each.

Assume i navigate this way

Home > Act1 > SubAct1a > SubAct1b > Home (through a Home button) > Act2 > Home > Act3

Now in Act3, when i press the phone BACK button, i get to Home. My REQUIREMENT at this point is when i press the BACK button again , it should EXIT the app. But what happens it it goes like this

Act2 > Home > SubAct1b > SubAct1a > Act1 > Home > EXIT

So the user is pressing BACK MULTIPLE times before he quits the app.

Pressing the HOME key is an option, but i want the BACK to work correctly as well.

I have this piece of code in the HOME activity - but it does not work at all

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It just returns to the previous activity it was at.

Comment: Because its just finishes your current activity.Other activities are still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return **true**, to tell the system that you already handled this situation,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

When you start your home activity, try setting the clear top flag...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I JUST tried that as well. But it doesnt work. It always goes back to the last activity that it was at.

Comment: That's how the back key is supposed to work.  Can you form a clearer example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: myintent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in your onCreate()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent i=new Intent(currentclass.this,Home.class)
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are going from one Activity to another Activity , finish the previous Activity. Then

override the back button and finish the current Activity if user press it, then i think your problem will be solved.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentclass.this, Act1.class)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

And finally

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
    }

    return true;
}
```